# How to use Cmake for OpenGL + Qt 5.8 in OS X Sierra?

Tags: macos, qt, opengl

I just tried to setup CMake for a project using Qt 5.8 to do OpenGL stuff in OS X Sierra. Here you can see my main CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set (PROJECT_NAME "FluidEngine")
project (${PROJECT_NAME})

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/BRabbit27/Qt/5.8/clang_64")
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package (Qt5Widgets)
find_package (Qt5Gui)
find_package (Qt5OpenGL)

set (CPP_SOURCES "")
set (HPP_SOURCES "")
set (INCLUDE_PATHS "")
add_subdirectory (src)

include_directories (${INCLUDE_PATHS} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_SOURCES} ${HPP_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL )
```

It perfectly configures the xcode project, no errors.
Then my code for rendering a basic triangle looks like:

```
GLWindow::GLWindow(QWidget* parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{}

void GLWindow::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    GLfloat verts[] =
    {
      0.f, 1.f,
     -1.f, -1.f,
      1.f, -1.f
    };

    GLuint myBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &myBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void GLWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void GLWindow::paintGL()
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

And what I get is a black window. I got this code from [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyue3MzJDss&list=PLRwVmtr-pp06qT6ckboaOhnm9FxmzHpbY&index=5)

Am I missing something in my cmake file or something subtle in OS X to use OpenGL? Since OS X is now promoting Metal, perhaps something must be enabled but I do not know what.

I already tried setting the version of OpenGL used in the main function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setVersion(4, 1);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    GLWindow glwindow;
    glwindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Added project to github, you can [clone it here](https://github.com/BRabbit27/fluidEngine.git) to test in your machine.

The way I build the project is just `cmake -GXcode ..` assuming i'm in `/path/to/project/build_xcode` directory.

Hope this can help you reproduce and perhaps give me a clue on what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked all the error messages and from there make my way to found the solution. Fortunately someone already replied in SO with a related problem and had a solution to the problem. You can find the complete answer here [OpenGL: INVALID_OPERATION following glEnableVertexAttribArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643027/opengl-invalid-operation-following-glenablevertexattribarray)

For short

> You're seeing this error on OS X because it only supports the OpenGL
>   Core Profile if you're using OpenGL 3.x or higher. Your code is not
>   Core Profile compliant. You were most likely using the Compatibility
>   Profile on Windows.
>
> Specifically, the Core Profile requires a Vertex Array Object (VAO) to
>   be bound for all vertex related calls. So before calling
>   `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`, or other similar functions, you will
>   need to create and bind a VAO.